# Dynamic incude page in xhtml page

Tags: jsf, jstl

I have a favourites chart, on click on an item in the chart, I have to inlcude a page in rich:tab. The favourites chart is built using jQuery and on each leaf click event I do a ui:include with jstl check. Please find the below code.

```
    <rich:tabPanel>
        <rich:tab label="#{mnOrdrMsgs.mainordr}" immediate="true"
            id="mainorderTab" styleClass="tabPanel">

            <c:if test="${favouritesBean.selectedNaviItem != null}">
                <ui:include src="#{favouritesBean.selectedPage}" />
            </c:if>

            </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab label="#{mnOrdrMsgs.archiv}" immediate="true"
            id="archivTab" styleClass="tabPanel">
        Archive
    </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
```

The problem is the value of favouritesBean.selectedPage is always null. Can anyone please help in this case. I am really stuck since 2 days.

Comment: How do you valued the `favouritesBean.selectedPage`? without this code this is difficult to help you...

Comment: Sorry here is the code!

first i set the value in the backing bean from javascript(code below). <br/>


<a4j:form>
<a4j:jsFunction name="updateTab" reRender="mainorderTab">  
     <a4j:actionparam name="naviItemSelected" assignTo="#
     {favouritesBean.selectedNaviItem}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
</a4j:form>

later in the bean the value is checked(code below)<br/>

public String getSelectedPage(){
     if(this.selectedNaviItem.equals("Auftragstemplateladen")){
      selectedPage="/protected/mainorder/auftragtemplate.xhtml";
     }
     return this.selectedPage;
    }<br/>

Is this the right way?

Comment: `selectedNaviItem` seems to never be equals to "Auftragstemplateladen". I think the problem come from the assignement of `favouritesBean.selectedNaviItem`. When and how do you call `updateTab` function?

Comment: apologies for indents as the comments space is limited.!

Comment: the updateTab value is updated on click of the item.

function onLiClick(thiss) {
 var clickText = myJQuery(thiss).text();
 if (clickText == 'Auftragstemplateladen') {
  alert('Auftragstemplateladen');
 }
 if (clickText == 'aus Formular') {
  alert('aus Formular');
 }
 if (clickText == 'Auftrag aus Archiv laden') {
  alert('Auftrag aus Archiv laden');
 }
 updateTab(clickText);
};

The value in the backing bean is set correctly and equals the Auftragstemplateladen, irrespective of the jstl <c:if test""> the ui:include is processed.

Comment: I Found out the solution. Thanks @Jean for your hint. The simple thing was my bean attribute selectedNaviItem were null for the first time render phase hence the selectedNaviItem was not evaluated and by default always the selectedPage value was being displayed. Now I have initialise the bean with empty string or default value. It works!!

Thank you very much.!!

Comment: You're welcome. Post your solution as an answer for others and mark it as "accepted answer".

Comment: @Jean : Ok. will take care. but since i have reputation less than 100. I cannot post answer before 8 hours :-) I will soon cope up with stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I think the problem come from the assignement of favouritesBean.selectedNaviItem."

> The bean attribute selectedNaviItem is null for the first time render phase hence the selectedNaviItem is not evaluated and by default always the selectedPage value is being displayed.

Solution:

> Initialise the bean with empty string or default value.

Answer (score 0):

JSTL tags doesn't run in sync with JSF tags as you'd expect from the coding. JSTL tags are executed during JSF view build time which produces a tree with JSF tags only. JSF tags are executed during JSF view render time which produces a tree with HTML elements only.

In this particular case, you want to use a JSF tag instead. Use `<ui:fragment>` or `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{favouritesBean.selectedNaviItem != null}">
    <ui:include src="#{favouritesBean.selectedPage}" />
</ui:fragment>
```